# Use a Property in a Class Sub or work with New

Tags: vb.net

I build one of my first classes and have a probably very simple question:
When i write:

```
Public Class DB_Query
Private myQueryA As String

Public Property QueryA As String
    Get
        QueryA = myQueryA
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        myQueryA = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Sub Send_Query
[...]
Dim mycmd as SqlCommand = SqlCommand(me.myQueryA, myconn)
[...]
End Sub
```

Is that the right way to do that since i always would have to set the "QueryA" before i can use the `Send_Query` method. Or do i have to work with an constructor?

Comment: Hi ruedi, I just want to check: are you asking whether your code is stylistically good, and whether there is a better way to handle your property `QueryA`?

Comment: Hi Dan. The second. If I use a Property in a Class' Sub then i always have to set the Property first because otherwise the Sub cannot be executed. So i would have to use a constructor (New()) to set the property first. is that right or do i missunderstand something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your property should always be set before the method is called, and can only be set once, then I would suggest a readonly property (with a private `set`) and that you set the value through the constructor.

However, if the property can be set more than once, then you need to leave the property as read-write. In that case you can't rely on the constructor, because it's always possible to set the property to an invalid value (e.g. `Nothing`) after the constructor is called. So in this case, I'd suggest that you make the `Send_Query` method throw a suitable exception (`InvalidOperationException`, perhaps) if you call the method when the property value is invalid.

Comment: Thank you! This helps a lot to decide what i have to do now.

Answer (score -1):

you can give your property a value one time, you can set it in your constructor or in any other function